# MPI Code runs successfully on one computer but not another?

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I have written some scientific software in C++ that makes use of MPI. I first wrote the code in serial and then wrote a parallel version (implemented with MPI). I completed a portion of the MPI code on my desktop at home, where it was tested against a known analytical solution as well as the serial code. It completed these successfully and the code is correct.

I later tested this code on an external cluster to understand the scaling as the number of processors is increased, and running with 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16 processors all led to a successful calculation.

I am now adding on to the code on my laptop and the output data diverges no matter the number of processors (even using 1 processor), although the identical (except for MPI-portions) serial code calculates the correct answer. At first I assumed that I accidentally changed something and reverted to an older version, only to find the same thing. I then went and ran the older version on the external cluster, where, to my surprise, it calculated the correct answer. I `scp`'d this code (tarballed it as-is from the cluster) back to my laptop and ran it with the exact same parameters, where I found that the output is incorrect (and divergent).

What could possibly cause this? I am running the latest version of OpenMPI (1.10.1) on OSX El Capitan, installed using Homebrew. I have tried both with `mpirun` and `mpiexec`, and they both give the same results. I am totally at a loss here.

One idea I did have was that it could be due to conflicting OpenMPI installs? I found that `anaconda` (the Python distribution) had its own version of OpenMPI, which I uninstalled (no change). As far as I can tell, there is no other version of MPI on my computer, but I suppose it is possible there is some conflicting library file lurking somewhere that is causing these issues.

Comment: Share code.  See MCVE.

Comment: Please distil down your algorithm into an MWE (minimal working example) that still reproduces the problem in question. Often the action of producing the MWE itself could lead you to finding the solution.